# Are disjoint unions coproducts?

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category, $X$ an object of $C$, and $i\colon A\to X$ and $j\colon B\to X$ monomorphisms (we say that $A$ and $B$ are subobjects of $X$, by abuse of language). Suppose these subobjects are disjoint. Does it follow that the union of $A$ and $B$ as *subobjects* is abstractly isomorphic to the coproduct $A+B$? The union of $A$ and $B$ is a new monomorphism $i\cup j\colon A\cup B\to X$. And the question is whether the domain of this morphism, $A\cup B$, is isomorphic to the coproduct $A+B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexamples are easily found in categories of algebraic objects (as long as you avoid abelian categories).  For instance, in the category of groups, take $X=S_3$ and let $A$ and $B$ be the subgroups generated by a 2-cycle and a 3-cycle, respectively.  These subgroups are disjoint (their meet in the lattice of subgroups is the least element, the trivial subgroup) and their join in the lattice of subgroups is the entire group $X$.  However, $X$ is not a coproduct of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks! But for abelian categories and toposes the answer is "yes"?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: In many useful "algebraic" categories, the hypothesis that the subobjects are disjoint is essentially never met, so the implication is vacuously, but not interestingly, correct. Vector spaces, abelian groups, groups, etc. In "sets", yes.

Comment: @paulgarrett: In this context "disjoint" is being used in a categorical sense, which is not necessarily the same as saying the underlying sets are disjoint.

Comment: @EricWofsey, ah! Thanks for the clarification. So, in the very tangible case of, say, abelian groups, the inevitable common $\{0\}$ is not relevant?

Comment: @paulgarrett: Right.  Roughly speaking, "disjoint" here means the intersection is the "trivial" subobject.

Comment: (Thanks much, @EricWofsey! Makes sense, philosophically, apparently, that "disjoint" means "trivial", in spirit, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Given any two nontrivial groups $G$ and $H$, $G \times H$ is a "disjoint union" of $G \times \{e_H\}$ and $\{e_G\} \times H$ (those subgroups are complements in the lattice of subgroups of $G \times H$), but it is not a coproduct (the coproduct is the free product $G*H$).